# how to cope with a null Date in an ibatis mapping

Tags: java, ibatis

I have the following in one of my result mappings.

```
<result property="updateDate" column="update_date" javaType="java.util.Date"
jdbcType="DATE" nullValue="01/01/1900"/>
```

basically `updateDate` is a setter that accepts `Date`.  However, sometimes `updateDate` will be `null` in the database.  In those cases I want to have a default date of `01/01/1900`.

However, the above mappings gives me the following error when `updateDate` is null from DB

```
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error setting property 'setUpdateDate'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that your nullValue="01/01/1900" is trying to pass a string into updateDate setter?  If you took that out, I assume the setter would be called by iBatis with 'null' and then you could apply the default in your setter in the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your updateDate method to take a null and set the "01/01/1900" Date in there?

This message can also occur when the setter doesn't exist or is spelled incorrectly too, make sure that's not the case.